# Find duplicate values in random order comma separated values in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column with comma separate values:

[image]

```
      A
1 abc,cbd,cdb
2 abc,cdd
3 abc,cdb,cbd
4 cdd,cbd,cdb
```

In above column 1 and 3 values are smilers but with different order how can I find this duplicate values (data is too large so I cannot do text to a column and then sorting).

This is actual data from which with 75k records which made it little complicated.

Comment: What you want to do with the duplicates once found? highlight? delete? copy somewhere else? Might worth adding some more details.

Comment: How 'large' is your data?

Comment: 75k records@ alowflyingpig

Comment: want to find unique values from comma separated values @ DarXyde

Answer (score 0):

Try in `B1`:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$A$1:$A$4),",",REPT(" ",LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$A$1:$A$4)))),(ROW()-1)*LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$A$1:$A$4))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$A$1:$A$4))))
```

Drag down.

Should give you all values in a list....you can remove duplicates after that.

Comment: That might do for that sample data, but i have a feeling that's not all of it `...data is too large...`

Comment: i dont know but its just giving #name value for all

Answer (score 0):

HEY GOT THE ANSWER HAVE TO ARRANGE THEM ALPHABETICALLY SO ON FILTER DUPLICATION OR UNIQUE IDENTIFICATION BECOME EASY

```
Sub SortString()
    Dim MyArray As Variant, varSwap As Variant
    Dim i As Long, min As Long, max As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim IsSwapped As Boolean

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set MyRange = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    For Each cell In MyRange
        MyArray = Split(cell.Value, ",")

        min = LBound(MyArray)
        max = UBound(MyArray) - 1
        Do
            IsSwapped = False
            For i = min To max
                If Trim(MyArray(i)) > Trim(MyArray(i + 1)) Then
                    varSwap = MyArray(i)
                    MyArray(i) = MyArray(i + 1)
                    MyArray(i + 1) = varSwap
                    IsSwapped = True
                End If
            Next
            max = max - 1
        Loop Until Not IsSwapped

        For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
            Debug.Print MyArray(i)
            If str = "" Then
                str = Trim(MyArray(i))
            Else
                str = str & ", " & Trim(MyArray(i))
            End If
        Next i
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = str
        str = ""
    Next cell
End Sub
```